# Deploy war to tomcat configuration issue

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7, web.xml

Trying to learn Ant/Tomcat and I'm running into some difficulty deploying my war.  I'm getting no errors in catalina, localhost, or localhost_access logs so I'm confident its just a configuration issue.  Ant build runs fine.  Deploys the war.  When I go to localhost:8080/antDemo/hello, I get a 404.  Code below.

One thing that is strange to me is that when I navigate to tomcat/webapps/antDemo I only see the HelloServlet.java file and a META-INF folder when I'd expect to see a web.xml and a classes folder or something like that.

I've read many stack overflow questions (whilst feeling like a moron for not being able to sort it out) but with no luck.

Help would be nice but even more so, some direction toward a comprehensive information resource that not only explains how things like this should be configured but WHY they need to be configured that way.  Getting the *why* has been harder to for me locate...and is the most important part.

Project Structure:

```
tomcatdemo
|-src
|---HelloServlet.java
|-WebContent
|---WEB-INF
|------classes
|---------HelloServlet.class
|------web.xml
|-build.xml
```

HelloServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGe(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>"); 
    }
}
```

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="clean" basedir=".">
    <property name="tomcat" value="C:\tomcat"/>
    <property name="tomcat.deployment" value="${tomcat}/webapps"/>
    <property name="tomcat.bin" value="${tomcat}/bin"/>
    <property name="base" value="."/>
    <property name="source" value="${base}/src"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete file="${tomcat.deployment}/antDemo.war"/>
        <antcall target="compile"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${base}/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" classpath="C:/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
        <antcall target="deployTarget"/>
    </target>


    <target name="warTarget">
        <war warFile="antDemo.war" webxml="${base}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${source}"/>
        </war>
        <antcall target="deployTarget"/>
    </target>

    <target name="deployTarget">
        <copy file="${base}/antDemo.war" todir="${tomcat.deployment}" />
        <antcall target="startTomcat"/>
    </target>

    <target name="startTomcat">
        <exec executable="${tomcat.bin}/startup.bat">
            <env key="CATALINA_HOME" value="${tomcat}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="stopTomcat">
        <exec executable="${tomcat.bin}/shutdown.bat">
            <env key="CATALINA_HOME" value="${tomcat}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app 
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" 
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>

    <display-name>myServletWAR, a first Web Application</display-name>
    <description>
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

EDIT: 
war structure is as follows (and its clearly wrong)

```
antDemo
|-META-INF
|----MANIFEST.MF
|-HelloServlet.java
```

Comment: Please send your `war` structure.

Comment: @AlexR what gets inflated by Tomcat? under /tomcat/webapps/antDemo/

Comment: What is the structure within your WAR file after it is built? You can unzip the WAR by renaming to .zip from .war.  This might help if the WAR file is not created properly. Having said that, I would have expected an error in the server logs.

Comment: @MichaelFreake - added it.  I don't understand why the war file isn't including the class after its compiled.  in the ant build.xml, when I compile the code, i write it to /WebContent/WEB-INF/classes.  Within eclipse, I can't see the actual class file but if i navigate to the workspace in explorer, I see it.  Should I be writing it somewhere else? under src maybe?  if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
            <fileset dir="${source}"/>
```

You should use

```
            <fileset dir="${base}/WebContent"/>
```

instead (untested).

Comment: thank you.  this was part of my problem.  in general, there was many fails in my build.xml.  This helped me ferret all of them out. Some additional fails were that my compile target was calling deploy target rather than war target.  as a result, subsequent builds weren't executing the war task so the same (broken) war kept getting deployed to tomcat (facepalm).  thanks again

Comment: it helps immensely to look inside the generated artifact to see what actually happened.  That said, if you are still struggeling to get started, I would suggest you switch from ant to maven.   You avoid these kind of problems, as Maven knows much more about your project than ant does.

Comment: it was very helpful...thank you.  Funny you should mention maven.  That's what I wanted to use (i've used it in past projects) but my new employer specifically said do not use maven.  oh well :)

Comment: If your new employer has a policy explicitly say "use ant, not maven" you might have experienced coworkers to ask.  They most likely have already seen any problem you might encounter.